# Check that a specific svn revision exists in the trunk

Tags: svn, command-line

In Windows subversion, in the trunk, I am trying to iterate over the revisions that exist in the trunk. I am trying to test to see if a specific revision number exists in the trunk. I need to build each trunk version in a range, but since the build is time consuming, I don't want to repeat builds.

The trunk has revisions:

11459
11458
11454
11453
etc.

I thought I could do something like

svn info svn://oursvnserver/ourproject/trunk -r 11456

and then check for an %ERRORLEVEL% return to see that there was no such revision in the trunk.

However, this returns the next earlier revision with a good return code. Something like:

URL: svn://oursvnserver/ourproject/trunk
...
Revision: 11456
...
Last Changed Rev: 11454

Is there a way without grep'ing the two revisions from the output, to ask subversion if this was a revision that was checked into the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tools can you use but the `log -q` command would be more usable in your case: `svn log -q svn://oursvnserver/ourproject/trunk` will print the revisions what you need (plus `---------------------` lines).

Maybe another possibility to use `svn log --xml` and process its output with an xml-program to see the revision numbers.